# Simple XOR example on theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I am a newbie for theano and I am failed to make simple XOR example with theano. I tried plenty things to make it work but it is seems that I just doing shamanism. Look at code it is pretty simple, but with it I got random results.

```
import numpy as np
import collections

import theano
import theano.tensor as T

INPUT_SIZE = 2
HIDDEN_SIZE = 2
OUTPUT_SIZE = 1

def train_2(data, valid_set_x):
    lr = 0.2

    x, y = data

    # symbol declarations
    ep = T.scalar()
    sx = T.matrix()
    sy = T.matrix()

    w1 = theano.shared(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(INPUT_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE)))
    b1 = theano.shared(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(HIDDEN_SIZE)))
    w2 = theano.shared(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(HIDDEN_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE)))
    b2 = theano.shared(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(OUTPUT_SIZE)))

    # symbolic expression-building
    hid = T.tanh(T.dot(sx, w1) + b1)
    out = T.tanh(T.dot(hid, w2) + b2)

    err = 0.5 * T.sum(out - sy) ** 2

    gw = T.grad(err, w1)
    gb = T.grad(err, b1)
    gv = T.grad(err, w2)
    gc = T.grad(err, b2)

    list = ((w1, w1 - (lr / ep) * gw),
            (b1, b1 - (lr / ep) * gb),
            (w2, w2 - (lr / ep) * gv),
            (b2, b2 - (lr / ep) * gc))

    dict = collections.OrderedDict(list)

    # compile a fast training function
    train = theano.function([sx, sy, ep], err, updates=dict)
    sample = theano.function([sx], out)

    train_set_size = x.shape[0]

    # now do the computations
    batchsize = 1
    for epoch in xrange(10):
        err = 0
        for i in xrange(train_set_size):
            x_i = x[i * batchsize: (i + 1) * batchsize]
            y_i = y[i * batchsize: (i + 1) * batchsize]
            err += train(x_i, y_i, epoch + 1)
        print "Error: " + str(err)

    print "Weights:"
    print w1.get_value()
    print b1.get_value()
    print w2.get_value()
    print b2.get_value()

    return sample(valid_set_x)

def test__(files=None):
    x_set = np.array([[-5, -5],
                      [-5, 5],
                      [5, -5],
                      [5, 5]]).astype("float32")
    y_set = np.array([[-0.9], [-0.9], [-0.9], [0.9]]).astype("float32")

    print "Processing..."
    result_set_x = train_2((x_set, y_set), x_set)

    print x_set
    print result_set_x
    print y_set

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test__()
```

Comment: You may want to follow the following Theano tutorial (with XOR example) to fully understand the basics of Theano before getting your hands dirty with it: http://outlace.com/Beginner-Tutorial-Theano/ Check also the slides 33 and 34 of this pdf for a very concise and clear XOR example: http://speech.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~tlkagk/courses/MLDS_2015_2/Lecture/Theano%20DNN.pdf

Comment: I read first link and remember when I made simple XOR on C++ which needs only 10 epochs to gain some qulaity as this one. with 10000 epoches this is just abnormal

Comment: 10 epochs seems a bit low, but the number of iterations it takes to converge can depend on the weight initialization, batch size, learning rate, activation function, optimizer chosen... altough 10,000 iterations for training a XOR does seem abnormally high

Comment: @galloguille By some means I reduced number of iterrations to 1000, but it still to high for me. I will try manually make back propagation. I think that tensor.gradient do not work properly

Comment: Is the code you provided still producing random results? Or you got it working?

Comment: Yes code perform well. I made hand back propagation version also and it is seems that it has same perfomance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your update section. I renamed the variable to 'updates' as 'list' and 'dict' are reserved words; not a good choice. Also, I do not know why you want to reduce your learning rate so fast, I removed that.
The updates should be an array like here

```
updates = [(w1, w1 - lr * gw),
           (b1, b1 - lr * gb),
           (w2, w2 - lr * gv),
           (b2, b2 - lr * gc)]

# compile a fast training function
train = theano.function([sx, sy], err, updates=updates)
```

I ran the changed example and got the result below. It needs more iterations to reduce the loss, but apart from that, it is ok.

```
Processing...
Error: 1.4456279556
...
Error: 0.0767515052046
Weights:
[[ 0.52955082 -1.26936557]
 [-1.05887804  0.04998216]]
[ 0.29209577 -0.22703456]
[[-0.89983822]
 [-0.88619565]]
[-0.86047891]
[[-5. -5.]
 [-5.  5.]
 [ 5. -5.]
 [ 5.  5.]]
[[-0.98989634]
 [-0.68941057]
 [-0.7034631 ]
 [ 0.72087948]]
[[-0.89999998]
 [-0.89999998]
 [-0.89999998]
 [ 0.89999998]]
```